# How to set schema and handle case of attribute names when using JRuby, ActiveRecord, and JDBC to access MS SQLserver

Tags: sql-server, activerecord, jdbc, schema, jruby

I had two problems to access SQL server database:

- how to set schema

The table I need to access is under schema 'general' instead of 'dbo'. Unless I use set_table_name, I will get errors like 'Invalid object'

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "general.Role"
end
```

Is there another way to set schema in the properties of jdbc url. I checked MS jdbc driver and jtds driver, but cannot find such a property.

- how to handle attribute names

When accessing db2, all attributes names are lower case. But for mssql, the attribute names are kept as the same case as defined in the database, for example, "RoleID". I'm wondering if only db2 driver forces attribute names to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

IN T-SQL, a fully qualified object name is `<database>.<owner>.<objectname>`.  Note that what your asking about is the *owner* not the schema (I guess you are coming from Oracle land?).

Given that it's the object owner, not the "schema you're connected to" (as in the Oracle paradigm), I don't think it makes sense to "connect to an owner", which is really what you're asking.

Using the `set_table_name` method you've described is perfectly valid for this case.  Even if your `Role` table was owned by dbo, you would still have to use set_table_name, as by default ActiveRecord will look for "role" (and it's case sensitive).

Comment: Yes. you are right. I use oracle/db2/mysql most of time. But I am still right, "general" in my example IS SCHEMA. SQL server 2005 and later have "User-Schema Separation". When I open the properties of the table in "Microsoft SQL server Management Studio", it is called "Schema". If I run the following sqls:

     select * from sys.schemas;
     select * from sys.database_principals;

it did shows general is a schema with pricipal_id=1, which is "dbo".

I know we can use set_table_name, but it means your code is fixed on SQL server, you cannot move to another db without a change.